# unable to get local issuer certificate - Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, openssl

I'm facing a strange issue. My vps from Linode has no issue connecting to apple push server with following command.

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert Test_dev_apns_cert.pem -key Test_dev_apns_key.pem
```

However, I was using the same **pem** files with above command testing from my another low budget vps and I'm getting this:

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

Both are running Ubuntu 11.04 and installed LAMP as usual. No special configuration is done to both servers for SSL.
Am I missing something here?